# Make a Valid Line Break inside a <ul> tag

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make a line break in a `<ul>` tag? If I do it this way it is not Valid HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <strong>Lorem Impsum</strong>
      <br>
      <span>Lorem Impsum<a href="https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?hl=de">https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?hl=de</a>
      </span>
   </li>
   <br> 
   <li>
      <strong>Lorem Impsum Pimpsum</strong>
      <br>
      <span>Loren Impsum <a onclick=”alert(‘Google Analytics wurde deaktiviert’);” href="javascript:gaOptout();">Google Analytics deaktivieren</a></span>
   </li>
   <br>
   <li>
      <strong>Pimpsum Impsum</strong>
      <br>
      <span>Lorem Impsum</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

What would be the correct way to do a Line Break between the `<strong>` and `<span>` tags?

Comment: `display: block` on the span?

Comment: Who says it's not?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 the W3C Validator

Comment: Would it be valid if it was self-closing like <br />?

Comment: @YoKoGFX `<br>`  between `<li>`s is not, while `<br>` *inside* `<li>` is.

Comment: it's breaking and working , why it's not valid!!

Comment: Why would you have a `br` in between `lis`? Use CSS! Simple padding/margin

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫  MDN also says it's invalid -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: @Keith Read my comment again.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫  What -> `Who says it's not?`  Maybe your best deleting a comment if you've changed your mind,. I tend to read comments in order from top to bottom..

Comment: @Keith You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47229560/make-a-valid-line-break-inside-a-ul-tag?noredirect=1#comment81409669_47229560)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫  That link is this page, and it still say `Who says it's not?`..

Comment: @Keith Read the comment that is highlighted. Tldr: No `<br>` allowed between `<li>`s, but `<br>`s are allowed inside `<li>`s. The question OP asked was "*What would be the correct way to do a Line Break between the <strong> and <span> tags?*", and my response is that it is always allowed.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫  I did read that, did you not read my other comment about deleting your first, as I tend to read comments from top to bottom, that's what my initial comment was in regard too, may I suggest you delete that one, and I'll deleting mine, as it's just a waste of pixels.

Comment: @Keith I don't see any reason in deleting my comment as it is a valid question. The W3C validator never says that putting `<br>` inside `<li>`s is invalid.

Comment: Fair enough, so nothing wrong with my initial comment either. `MDN' saying invalid, so was no need for me to re-read anything..

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Your answer worked, I put the `<br>` inside the `<li>` and now it shows Valid :) I also used `display: block` in the `<spans>` so I don't need the `<br>` in this case. So the only `<br>` is now under the `</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li>
  <strong>Lorem Impsum</strong>
  <br>
  <span>Lorem Impsum<a href="https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?
hl=de">https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?hl=de</a>
  </span>
```

now you want line break between strong and  span.

try this

**Lorem Impsum**

```
  <li style="list-style:none"><span>Lorem Impsum<a href="https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?
hl=de">https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?hl=de</a>
  </span></li>
```